Running multiple loops at the same time in Python? (Zelle graphics)
I'm taking an intro to python class and my final project is to make a game/program. I'm making is an infinite runner game, similar to the google (no wifi) dinosaur game. I'm trying to get two loops to run at the same time so the obstacles are constantly moving/spawning, and so the player can jump to avoid them. I'm also trying to get other pieces of code to work while the loops are running, such as the quit button already added, and for other pieces of code I add later on to work during the loop.
I've looked around for answers and all I see is people saying to use threading, which I haven't figured out how to make work and don't really understand it.
(sorry about the messy/disorganized code)
from graphics import *
import time

#############
# Variables #
#############
gecko = "gecko.gif"
savannah = "savannah.gif"
keeled = "keeled.gif"
lacerta = "lacerta.gif"
watermtr = "watermonitor.gif"
komodo = "komodo.gif"

lizard = komodo


win = GraphWin("Game", 1500, 750)

class Button():
    # Utilizes a Rectangle and Text to draw both with less code
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, text):
        self.rectangle = Rectangle(p1, p2)
        self.text = Text(
            Point((p1.getX() + p2.getX())/2, (p1.getY() + p2.getY())/2),
            text)
   
    def draw(self, graphwin):
        self.rectangle.draw(graphwin)
        self.text.draw(graphwin)

def clickedInside(button, mouse):
    if (mouse.getX() >= button.rectangle.getP1().getX()
        and mouse.getX() <= button.rectangle.getP2().getX()
        and mouse.getY() >= button.rectangle.getP1().getY()
        and mouse.getY() <= button.rectangle.getP2().getY()):
        return True
    return False

quitButton = Button(Point(1425, 10), Point(1485, 35), "Quit")


def character():
    global characterXY
    global hitBoxSize
    global background
    if lizard == gecko:
        background = "geckobackground.gif"
        characterXY = Point(715, 375)
        hitBoxSize = Rectangle(Point(670, 435), Point(830, 350))
    elif lizard == savannah:
        background = "savannahbackground.gif"
        characterXY = Point(710, 375)
        hitBoxSize = Rectangle(Point(655, 435), Point(845, 385))
    elif lizard == keeled:
        background = "keeledbackground.gif"
        characterXY = Point(685, 425)
        hitBoxSize = Rectangle(Point(670, 435), Point(830, 370))
    elif lizard == lacerta:
        background = "lacertabackground.gif"
        characterXY = Point(700, 410)
        hitBoxSize = Rectangle(Point(690, 435), Point(810, 365))
    elif lizard == watermtr:
        background = "watermonitorbackground.gif"
        characterXY = Point(670, 410)
        hitBoxSize = Rectangle(Point(690, 435), Point(810, 385))
    elif lizard == komodo:
        background = "komodobackground.gif"
        characterXY = Point(685, 398)
        hitBoxSize = Rectangle(Point(690, 435), Point(810, 375))
character()

def startUp():
    lizardRunner = Text(Point(750, 10), "Lizard Runner")
    lizardRunner.setFace("courier")
    lizardRunner.setSize(36)
    lizardRunner.draw(win)
    for i in range(335):
        lizardRunner.move(0, 1)
        time.sleep(0.001)
# startUp()


    

def main():
    hitBox = hitBoxSize
    player = Image(characterXY, lizard)
    ground = Line(Point(0, 437), Point(1500, 437))
    ground.setWidth(3)
    gameBackground = Image(Point(750, 375), background)
    obstacle = Image(Point(1525, 415), "cactus.gif")
    gameBackground.draw(win)
    ground.draw(win)
    obstacle.draw(win)
    Image.draw(player, win)
    quitButton.draw(win)
    mouse = win.getMouse()


    while True:
        if(mouse != None and clickedInside(quitButton, mouse)):
            win.close()
        obstacle.move(-1, 0)
        if win.getKey() == "space" or win.getKey() == "w":
            for i in range(15):
                player.move(0, -6)
                hitBox.move(0, -6)
                time.sleep(0.00001)
            for i in range(15):
                player.move(0, 6)
                hitBox.move(0, 6)
                time.sleep(0.00001)

def movingParts():
    obstacle = Image(Point(1525, 415), "cactus.gif")
    obstacle.draw(win)
    for i in range(1550):
        obstacle.move(-1, 0)
        time.sleep(0.001)

def chooseLizard():
    pickWin = GraphWin("Choose your lizard", 1000, 550)
    character = Image(Point(500, 275), keeled)
    Image.draw(character, pickWin)
    pickWin.getMouse()
#chooseLizard()

main()


Using threading is really not a good idea. You then need to care about thread synchronization and threading issue (things like race conditions) which are a mess for beginners. Instead you can play with coroutine (or async programming). An alternative solution is just to adapt your code so not to need this (not always possible with some GUI systems but unusual not to have any way of doing that beside multithreading).
